# copy postfix/dovecot/imapsync configuration to new pc

Tags: server, postfix, mail-server, imap

TL;DR Fast and easy way to copy postfix/dovecot/imapsync configuration to new pc?

First of all, I almost have no clue on how email and email servers work.

Moving on, I have an old server with an old broken ubuntu installation without GUI. I bought a new pc to replace it.
I tried a mad shot by replacing the hard drive in the new PC with the one from the old one, remotely hoping it would boot and update drivers, packages etc. As I expected, it couldn't boot due to Secure Boot and who-knows-what.
The old server was running a postfix server to receive email, and imapsync to periodically synchronize every 2 mins  with the actual email service provider (e.g. gmail.com) . I've noticed that also dovecot is installed, but i'm unsure on what its role is.
Local Thunderbird clients in the office use this server to see only received email (which I suppose it downloads it from "gmail.com" using imapsync), they send emails using directly the mail provider MDA.

The configuration of this system is kinda unconventional and doesn't seem to match the many ones which are discussed in videotutorials and articles.

I don't understand how these postfix/dovecot/imapsync are configured and interact with each other to make this odd sorcery work. I need to replace the server without having to reconfigure the clients and I don't know how to configure the software from scratch to do so.

Is there any fast way to copy the configuration of the software from the old pc to the new one?

Thank you for your help and time.